# Removing sub-items from an ObservableCollection in Xamarin Forms CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a grouped model defined as:

```
public class CalendarGroupModel : List<CalendarModel>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string DateLabel { get; set; }
        public double CompletePercentage { get; set; }
        public string CompleteLabel { get; set; }

        public CalendarGroupModel(string name, List<CalendarModel> calendarEntries) : base(calendarEntries)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

The sub-model CalendarModel is defined as:

```
public class CalendarModel
    {
        public int CalendarID { get; set; }
        public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The group model is then used as an ObservableCollection for a ListView:

```
public ObservableCollection<CalendarGroupModel> CalendarGroupModels { get; }
```

How do I delete one of the sub-model CalendarModels from the ObservableCollection? When I try to access the inner list it doesn't seem to be possible.

I am unsure how to access the sub-model items and remove them from the ObservableCollection.

**Update:**

I am able to remove items from the 2D array using:

```
foreach (var e in CalendarGroupModels)
                {
                    foreach (var a in e)
                    {
                        if (a.CalendarID == calendarTable.CalendarID)
                        {
                            CalendarGroupModels[CalendarGroupModels.IndexOf(e)].Remove(a);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

However, the UI does not update if you remove from the sub-list.

I have tested removing root items and the UI does update as expected.

```
CalendarGroupModels.RemoveAt(1);
```

How can I get the UI to update when removing items from the sub-list?

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Posting code as images is against the site rules.  Please take the time to paste the relevant code as text and properly format it

Comment: Thank you for the 'How To' pointer. I have updated the post as required.

Comment: `CalendarGroupModels` is basically a 2D array.  To remove an element, `CalendarGroupModels[x].Remove(element)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the UI does not update if you remove from the sub-list.

For this, you can try to define the parent class  and the parameter of constructor of class `CalendarGroupModel` as type `ObservableCollection<CalendarModel>`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
  public class CalendarGroupModel : ObservableCollection<CalendarModel>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string DateLabel { get; set; }
        public double CompletePercentage { get; set; }
        public string CompleteLabel { get; set; }

        public CalendarGroupModel(string name, ObservableCollection<CalendarModel> calendarEntries) : base(calendarEntries)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```